# Change UIButton border color after tapping it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have customized my own button. I want to change the button textcolor and the border color when I tap on it. I override the UIButton setHighlighted method by the following code

```
if (highlighted) {
    self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.447 green:0.443 blue:0.443 alpha:1.000] CGColor];
    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.447 green:0.443 blue:0.443 alpha:1.000];
}
else{
    self.layer.borderColor = [[ UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

However, it won't work when I just tap the button, and it would change the color when I made a move on the button.
I tried to create the breakpoint to check whether this function could be entered correctly. I observed that these codes would be executed once when I just tap the button(triggered by touchbegan event), but be executed twice when I further move on it(triggered by touchbegan, touchmove event ).

I also try to add the action on the view level:

```
[downloadBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(allDownloadBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[downloadBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(allDownloadBtnHighlighted:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

But it still can't be operated as my expection.

Anyone could give me any suggestion to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: Did you set self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f for your button ?

Comment: I've set the borderWidth in the layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self addCustomFeature];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self addCustomFeature];
}

#pragma mark CustomizeUI
- (void)addCustomFeature
{
    // creating curved corners
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:5];
    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

}

- (void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor
{
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [self.layer setBorderColor:borderColor.CGColor];
}

- (void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
        if (highlighted) {
            self.borderColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        else {
            self.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
}
```

Comment: I've set the borderWidth in the layoutSubviews function.
And the answer still can't work.

Comment: @kuokuo321: Did you called the super class method ?

Comment: both in layoutSubviews and setHighlighted I've called the super class method first.

Comment: @kuokuo321: Try setting the borderWidth inside the setHighlighted method.

Comment: It still can't work when I just tap this button.
BTW, I set the showTouchwhenHighlighted = YES, and I can see the button with tap effect, but the border keeps in white color...

Comment: Originally, I've set this attribute(setMasksToBounds) to YES. But I've tried to change this property to NO, and both setting can't let the border color be changed.

Comment: I just created a sample project now for checking your issue. Its working for me, I will update the code now. Please check that.

Comment: Although this solution could change the border color correctly, I still can't understand the difference between my original code. Also, this solution still can't change the button text color in the setHighLighted function, I can use the work around solution by set the highlighted color previously.

Comment: Use this code to set the title color : [self setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selected flag inside your touch up inside method:

```
- (void)allDownloadBtnClicked:(UIButton*)sender{ 
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    ...
}
```

and override the setSelected function instead

```
- (void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected{
    [super setSelected:selected];
    if (selected) {
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.447 green:0.443 blue:0.443 alpha:1.000] CGColor];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.447 green:0.443 blue:0.443 alpha:1.000];
    }
    else{
        self.layer.borderColor = [[ UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but the result is it can enter this function but can't change the border color. BTW, I use the Xcode 6.4 and connected to my iPhone 6+ to test this function.

Comment: @kuokuo321 only the borderColor is not working ? textColor is set ?